# using relative addressing for API inside Axios request

Tags: reactjs, axios, relative-addressing

I'm working on an application where the URL/path to the API's CRUD functions are defined like so:

```
var newApiAddresses = {
        itemsGet: "<?php echo $view['router']->url('itembook_test_api_v1_apiitems_getitems'); ?>",
        itemAdd: "<?php echo $view['router']->url('itembook_test_api_v1_apiitems_itemadd'); ?>",
        itemEdit: "<?php echo $view['router']->path('itembook_test_api_v1_apiitems_itemedit', array('id' => null)); ?>",
        itemDelete: "<?php echo $view['router']->path('itembook_test_api_v1_apiitems_itemdelete', array('id' => null)); ?>"
    }
```

As expected the path for edit and delete receive an id. Now in my application I can create a post and get request with the urls defined in this manner like so:

```
  handlePostItemToApi () {
    axios.post(newApiAddresses.itemAdd, {
      "itemId": 1,
      "date": this.changeDateFormat(),
      ...
```

The above sends the POST request with no problem. But when I need to edit an item, I need to somehow include the itemid into this url. I tried doing it like so but it did not work

```
  handleEditItemToApi () {
    axios.put(newApiAddresses.itemEdit/{$id}, {
      "itemId": 1,
      "date": this.changeDateFormat(),
      ...
```

What is the correct way to include the id in the above url for put. I cannot hardcode the url like e.g. 'http://localhost/app_dev.php/api/v1/items/{$id}' as shown in axios documentation

Comment: don't know if it's a typo but you're sending the `put` to `itemAdd` instead of `itemEdit` , try : `axios.put(newApiAddresses.itemEdit, { "itemId" : {$id}, "date" : ...`

Comment: @taki yes it is a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the back quotes(not the usual single quote) in following way,

```
 axios.put(`newApiAddresses.itemEdit/{$id}`, {
```

or using the single quote as,

```
axios.put('newApiAddresses.itemEdit/'+id, {
```

Comment: Can you paste the request url that u can see from your network monitor

Comment: i don't know if this is the right one but here: REQUEST_URI 
"/app_dev.php/itemss/newApiAddresses.itemEdit/3"

Comment: sorry this is the right one:  
REQUEST_URI 
"/app_dev.php/flights/newApiAddresses.itemEdit/%7B$id%7D"

Comment: I dont think thats the right one, pls check again. If you can see the previously posted url, it must have worked. and the %7B$id%7D is the url encoded value of {$id} which must have gone before u made the change. Pls clear the log and reverify.

Comment: the previous one is from i added /id to the end. this is the one after I refreshed the page and edited a field. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Ok, can you paste the req url after u try with the second method

Comment: "/app_dev.php/items/newApiAddresses.itemEdit/%7B$id%7D"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171855/discussion-between-rohith-murali-and-jimiss).

Comment: so this the correct answer. The ' ' have to be removed. axios.put(newApiAddresses.itemEdit+id, {